# certs are imported. But can not list them

Tags: java, keytool

In my new windows 10 laptop I successfully imported some certs:

```
 C:\windows\system32>keytool -import -trustcacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias <cert name> -file C:/ca-certs/<cert name>.crt -cacerts -v
Certificate was added to keystore
[Storing C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-17\lib\security\cacerts]
```

Then I tried to list them. But I am getting this exception:

```
    C:\windows\system32>keytool -list
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\tester\.keystore
```

-import command imported the certs to the cacerts file. But the -list command tries to find it from .keystore file.
Did I miss any configuration.
I remember I did the same thing in my older laptop but I did not have issues.

Comment: You specified `-cacerts` on the `-import`; to list the same file use it on the `-list` also. Note this will list _everything_ in the file: both the cert(s) you just imported, and about a hundred that were already there. To list only a single new one, do `keytool -list -cacerts -alias {name}`. But this is not a programming or development issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "keytool" program [defaults to a keystore called ".keystore" in your home directory](https://megamorf.gitlab.io/cheat-sheets/java-keystores/), not the keystore you just created.

> By default the keytool will generate a keystore in the user’s home directory (Linux/macOS: `$HOME/.keystore`, Windows: `$env:USERPROFILE/.keystore`). Use the `-keystore` parameter to specify a custom path.

Add the "-keystore" option to specify the location of the keystore file you created.

```
C:\windows\system32> keytool -list -keystore "C:/ca-certs/<cert name>.crt"
Enter keystore password: <YourPasswordHere>
```

That will list everything, but you can filter it by your alias if needed:

```
C:\windows\system32> keytool -list -keystore "C:/ca-certs/<cert name>.crt" -alias "<cert name>"
Enter keystore password: <YourPasswordHere>
```

More examples of keytool commands are at [The Most Common Java Keytool Keystore Commands](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html).

Comment: `keytool -import -file c:/ca-certs/name.crt` specified the _input_ file which was read to get the cert that was then imported; it was neither created nor updated, and it was not a keystore and still is not a keystore so you can't `-list` it.